# Danby Mini-fridge not Cooling

Tags: repair, refrigerator, compressor, relay

I have a Danby Designer mini fridge (‎[FBA_DCR032A2BDD](https://www.danby.com/products/compact-refrigerators/dcr032a2bdd/)) that stopped cooling recently. This fridge was only been manufactured in 2019 so it feels like a waste to throw it out without at least attempting to fix it.

I did some research and found that it might be the [PTC & OLP Combination 2.6SM4R](https://www.danbyapplianceparts.ca/product/ptc-overload-protector-combination/) relay that needs to be replaced. I have some experience with repairs so I thought I would give it a shot.

When I was able to look at the fridge, it was still plugged in, so I unplugged it. What concerns me is that **the compressor was very warm to the touch** despite the fridge no longer cooling.

## Question

Is it possible for the compressor to warm up if the relay is broken, or could this indicate the fault is elsewhere?

I included the electrical diagram if this would shed some light on someone more familiar with fridge repair:

[image]

## Additional Info

- The back of the fridge seems to only have the power cable, the relay and housing, and the compressor. I do not see any kind of fan or coils. I included a picture of the back on the white version of this mini fridge if it helps.

[image]

Comment: there are numerous failure modes where the compressor would run but the unit not cool.

Comment: Grab your multimeter and see if you're getting voltages at appropriate locations when it's supposed to be running. You might have a broken wire, a short, a loose connection, who knows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it **is** a bad start relay as you suspect, the motor could be quite warm from failing to start but having current running through it.

However, it could also be a refrigerant leak causing the fridge to run but not cool, and this sort of fridge is not made to be economically sensible to do refrigeration circuit work on - the valves are not there, it's only intended to work until it doesn't and be discarded, because getting it repaired will cost more than replacing it with a new cheaply built fridge like it.